# Swift, derived classes with same named static function

Tags: swift, static-methods

I want to have the same named static function for multiple classes which are derived from each other.  I really don't feel like naming them G_something, H_something, etc.

Is there any way in swift to do this:

```
class G {
    static func dosomething()
    {
        print("G")
    }
}

class H : G {
    class func dosomething()
    {
        G.dosomething()
        print("H")
    }
}

class I : H {
    class func dosomething()
    {
        H.dosomething()
        print("I")
    }
}

I.dosomething()
```

Comment: You could use class functions and `override` them, and use `super.dosomething()` to call the superclass method. But it's not really clear why you want to do this, so without knowing your use case, there's not much more people will be able to offer.

Comment: This isn't possible, because calling `I.doSomething()` becomes ambiguous.

Comment: "without knowing your use case, there's not much more people will be able to offer." exactly this. I can't really help without having more information about the problem you're trying to solve. You've only shown your attempt at a solution and asking us to address that. It's an XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/219397

Comment: @Alexander - I can't understand your comment, until you tell me how my response to your comment will impact you.  It's an XY problem.

Comment: @iamacomputer Haha meta, but I don't follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be short :

```
class G {
    class func dosomething()
    {
        print("G")
    }
}

class H : G {
    override class func dosomething()
    {
        super.dosomething()
        print("H")
    }
}

class I : H {
    override class func dosomething()
    {
        super.dosomething()
        print("I")
    }
}

I.dosomething()
```

> G
>
> H
>
> I

Answer (score 1):

Simple overriding should works:

```
class G {
    class func dosomething()
    {
        print("G")
    }
}

class H : G {
    override class func dosomething()
    {
        super.dosomething()
        print("H")
    }
}

class I : H {
    override class func dosomething()
    {
        super.dosomething()
        print("I")
    }
}


I.dosomething()
```